# update table in html body by copying element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, console

I have html page whose body contains a table which has certain data in each cell.
I have another similar page but without data in table cells.

Everytime I add value to cell it sends post call to update data in db I guess.
I copied table element from first html page and pasted in second one which fills all cell data, but it doesn't send post call.

Is there way to do it, because when I refresh page table shows empty again.

Answer (score 0):

When you past text (or type it) into a field or page, it updates the existing DOM with that data - but it's utterly ephemeral. In other words, it's not saved anywhere and is temporary. When you refresh the page, the data all disappears as it redraws the DOM from the code - which doesn't include the temporary updates you've made.

To fix this, there are two options, depending on whether your first and second page pull from the same database and table or not.

1) If you're updating a database with your data every time you update the first page, then you can have the 2nd page load the data from that same database. You don't need to paste it at all. As soon as the post is made on the 1st page, you refresh the 2nd page and you'll see the change.

2) If you want the second page to save the data from pasting into it, then you could use the `jquery` `.change()` function on the table cells to do an `$.ajax` call, which updates the database. You'd still need to re-code the 2nd page to populate based on database data so it's there when you refresh, but you'd then also have the functionality of it updating when you pasted into it.